# Is there a mobile app to cache the content of a private MediaWiki instance?

Tags: mobile, rss, mediawiki, caching

I'm a webmaster at an organization that has a private wiki. We have a MediaWiki instance hosted on a GoDaddy shared hosting environment. My supervisor is asking that we have an app for our employee's mobile devices that can work offline, so that employees can view the information on our wiki when they are someplace that doesn't have wireless service.

In other words, we want a mobile app that can cache some of the content of our private MediaWiki instance on the user's phone.

Something like this, ideally, should exist, given that MediaWiki is an open-source project, and is the CMS for one of the biggest websites in the world (wikipedia). If an app doesn't exist exist to view and cache an arbitrary MediaWiki instance, perhaps we could:

- modify the source code for the Wikipedia app; OR
- we could find an app that caches the contents of an Atom/RSS feed, and then use MediaWiki extensions to place recently-accessed and recently-modified articles into a news feed

Thoughts?

**Edit:**
Our crew is using their own personal smartphones; they are not using company phones.  So, half of them have Android and half of them have iPhones.  We are considering providing company phones, which would be iPhones.

Since most mobile apps have both iPhone and Android versions released (AFAIK), it should be a non-issue which mobile platform we are using.  However, if we were forced to choose, we would choose iPhone.

Comment: The mobile app's os would be what? IOS, Android, Windows Phone, etc.

Comment: I don't have a step by step guide, but http://www.kiwix.org/ produces apps for all sorts of MediaWiki wikis (and subsets thereof). Once you install Parsoid, you can run [mwoffliner](https://sourceforge.net/p/kiwix/other/ci/master/tree/mwoffliner/) to produce a ZIM file out of it (highly compressed dump of HTML+images). It's then trivial to load such ZIM file on Kiwix.